# Can managed capabilities be installed with (install-capability) outside the module in which they are defined?

Tags: pact-lang

Is it possible to install a managed capability outside the module it was defined, without signing the capability in the transaction data?

For example, I would like to use the `coin.transfer-create` function within a function implemented in my module in order to transfer funds from a module-controlled account to a user account. This function is guarded by the `coin.TRANSFER` managed capability.

I can call my module function (which itself calls `coin.transfer-create`) if I sign the transaction with the `coin.TRANSFER` capability in the capabilities list. However, I want my module to allow arbitrary user accounts to ask for KDA from the module account, without having to provide the `coin.TRANSFER` capability in the capabilities list (after all, they don't know the module account's private key). (This contract is only intended for testnet.)

I'd like to do something like this:

```lisp
(defun my-fn (user-account:string amount:decimal)
  ; install the capability, without relying on it being in the capabilities list
  (install-capability (coin.TRANSFER "contract-account" user-account amount))
  ; grant the capability
  (with-capability (coin.TRANSFER "contract-account" user-account amount)
    <execute transfer>))
```

The code written above gives a keyset failure in the REPL. Is it possible to install a managed capability from outside the module in which it was defined?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you cannot use `with-capability` outside of the module where the capability is defined. But since coin.TRANSFER is a managed capability, we've got `install-capability` available which might be enough.

As @georgep said, the "keyset failure" error is not indicative of a capability issue, there's a "missing capability" error for those.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I have done this for a module-guard account. Not all keyset failures are equal. Having the full error message might shed more light. Such as missing signature for gas payer or so.